# Groovy split on period and return only first value

Tags: groovy

I have the input as

`var = primarynode.domain.local`

and now I Need only `primarynode` from it.

I was looking both split and tokenize but not able to do it in one line code. does anyone know how to do it in one line code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Well assuming that you want to just get the first word(before `.` )
>   from the input string.

You can use the `tokenize` operator of the String

If you have

```
def var = "primarynode.domain.local"
```

then you can do

```
def firstValue = ​var.tokenize(".")[0]​
println firstValue
```

output

```
primarynode
```

Comment: Thanks. i was missing "[0]" part.

Answer (score 12):

The `split` method works, you just have to be aware that the argument is a regular expression and not a plain String. And since "." means "any character" in a regular expression, you'll need to escape it...

```
var = 'primarynode.domain.local'.split(/\./)[0]
```

...or use a character class (the "." is not special inside a character class)

```
var = 'primarynode.domain.local'.split(/[.]/)[0]
```