# Substring after a character

Tags: string, groovy

I'm looking for a way to beautifully extract 'user id' from string in Groovy. Lets say I have string `"key::${userId}"` For example:

```
String s = "key::123456"
```

I can extract userId in java style as following

```
Long.parseLong(s.substring(s.indexOf("::") + 2))
```

But I believe that there is a way to make it shorter and more neatly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745839/groovy-split-on-period-and-return-only-first-value

Comment: The shortest: `s.split("::")[1] as long`

Comment: For golf sake: `s[5..-1]as long`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `key::` is always the prefix, you can use the `-` operator, combined with the `as` keyword for the String to long conversion:

```
String s = 'key::123456' 
long userId = (s - 'key::') as long
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple assignment operator combined with `tokenize` method:

```groovy
def (_,userId) = "key::123456".tokenize("::")

assert userId == "123456"
```